# Can't insert the row into database

Tags: php, sql

Why I can't insert into the database? What's wrong with my code?

```
<form action = "" method ="POST">                                           
    <center>                                               
        <b>Name</b><br><br>Quantity: <input type = "text" name = "name" style = "width: 155px"><br><br>                                         
        <b>Contact Number</b><br><br>Quantity: <input type = "text" name = "contact" style = "width: 155px" ><br><br>                                           
        <b>Address</b><br><br>Quantity: <input type = "text" name = "address" style = "width: 155px"><br><br>
        <b>Spoon N1(₱25000.00)</b><br><br>Quantity: <input type = "text" name = "Squantity" style = "width: 155px" value = "0"><br><br>
        <b>Tanabe Hypermedallion(₱15000.00)</b><br><br>Quantity: <input type = "text" name = "Tquantity" style = "width: 155px" value = "0"><br><br>
        <b>Fujitsubo Legalis R(₱15000.00)</b><br><br>Quantity: <input type = "text" name = "Fquantity" style = "width: 155px" value = "0"><br><br>
        <b>GCash Transaction No.</b><br>:      
        <input type = "text" name = "quantity" style = "width: 155px"><br><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
    </center>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = empty($_POST['name']) ? die ("Input a name"): mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $contact = empty($_POST['contact']) ? die ("Input a contact number"): mysql_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
    $address = empty($_POST['address']) ? die ("Input a address"): mysql_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $spoon = empty($_POST['Squantity']) ? die ("Input a value"): mysql_escape_string($_POST['Squantity']);
    $tanabe = empty($_POST['Tquantity']) ? die ("Input a value"): mysql_escape_string($_POST['Tquantity']);
    $fujitsubo =empty($_POST['Fquantity']) ? die ("Input a value"): mysql_escape_string($_POST['Fquantity']);
    $total = ($spoon * 25000) + ($tanabe * 15000) + ($fujitsubo * 15000);
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "password";
    $db = "eurocare";
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ("Unable to connect");
    $conn = mysql_select_db($db,$con);
    $query = "INSERT INTO orders(name, contact, address, spoon, tanabe, fujitsubo) VALUES ('$name','$contact','$address','$spoon','$tanabe','$fujitsubo','$total')";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die("Error in Query : $query ." .mysql_error());
    exit; 
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Comment: What does the `mysql_error()` give ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: `mysql_escape_string()` is obsolete. In fact, all of the `mysql_*` functions are.

Comment: I dont get any errors but when i press the button nothing happens

Comment: Just another question. I want to insert value 0 but the it is not accepted by the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submit button ie. HTML input element `<input type="submit" ... ...>` has to have the `"name"` attribute to be included in the `$_POST` array.

```
<input type = "submit" value = "submit" name="submit">
```

Without it `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` would never resolve to true.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `mysql_connect` is deprecated, use `mysqli` instead.**

I see you basically want to insert 7 elements, but declared only six...

```
INSERT INTO orders(name, contact, address, spoon, tanabe, fujitsubo) <-- @@!!SIX!!@@ VALUES ('$name','$contact','$address','$spoon','$tanabe','$fujitsubo','$total') <-- @@!!SEVEN!!@@
```